# Where to call for CSS/JS in custom component for frontend views

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, css, best-practices

I've created a custom component with a dashboard that needs styling with CSS. I've created the CSS file and I'm looking at calling for it in the frontend view.

Working with J! 3.6.5 and a `MVC` developed component obviously I'm confident that I need to place the following code in an appropriate place:

```
JHtml::_('stylesheet', 'com_mycomponent/css/dashboard.css');
```

My best guess was to put it between the "`public function display`" lines in my "`view.html.php`" file. However, this does not working so I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest placing it in your view file:

> components/com_mycomponent/views/VIEW_NAME/tmpl/default.php

This means that is anyone wishes to override your component views, they can, for example, remove your CSS file being referenced and use their own.

Comment: Right! That works! So is this the standard way of adding CSS files to views or is there a better way. For example if you want to add CSS that is used by multiple views?